# Python MySQL INSERT ONDUPLICATE KEY

Tags: python, mysql

I have a Python script that inserts data into a MySQL database, but to preserve the `id` values I want it so that if it finds the same name then it will just update the vuln_count column for that record.

I have the following MySQL insert code:

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO vuln_sets (vulntype, displayname, bulletinfamily, vulncount)"
                                " values (%s,%s,%s,%s,)", [k, vuln_name, vuln_bulletinfamily, vuln_count], "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE vulncount = values(%s)", [vuln_count])
```

But I have an error of `execute() takes from 2 to 3 positional arguments but 5 were given`

Comment: That's not how this works...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how `execute` works: it takes **two explicit parameters**: the **query**, and the **parameters**.

You can **not** write a part of the query followed by parameters followed by another part of the query and so on.

So you simply write it as a single query, and join the two lists of parameters together:

```
cur.execute(
    "INSERT INTO vuln_sets (vulntype, displayname, bulletinfamily, vulncount)"
    " VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s) ON DUPLICATE KEY"
    " UPDATE vulncount = %s",
    [k, vuln_name, vuln_bulletinfamily, vuln_count, vuln_count]
)
```

Comment: this just gives an error of: `1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE vulncount = VALUES (1765)' at line 1")`

Comment: @Luke: What if you remove the comma (edited answer).

Comment: Still the same issue, it's getting the correct value though. Its error 1064 if that helps??

Comment: For example `(1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '806)' at line 1")` the "806" is the correct value for vuln_count for that record

Comment: @Luke: did you actually tested your query before you posted. Beause `ON DUPLCATE KEY UPDATE vulncount` seems illegal syntax. Third attempt.

Comment: Yes and the wuery doesn't work. I'm not too up on MYSQL/MARIADB syntax

Comment: @Luke: I edited the answer by what I think is valid MySQL.

Comment: No, it's still complaining, this time near the `SET vulncount = %s`

Comment: @Luke: well I think we make progress, since it is a different error. New attempt.

Comment: @Luke: can you please just check that it does *not* update every row in case of duplicate key. Although I think it does not, we better be safe than sorry.

Comment: Just checked, I only have 100 records in the table which is the right number!